# Does an ICE ticket apply to the S-Bahn?

Tags: trains, public-transport, deutsche-bahn, muc

I will arrive Munich Airport next month. On the same day, I'll travel to Nuremberg from Munich Hbf. I'll take the S-Bahn from Munich Airport to Munich Hbf. Can I use the ICE ticket that I purchased online on the S-Bahn train from the airport to Munich Hbf station? Can I use the same ticket on the underground of Nuremberg (U1 line)?

Comment: Do the ICE ticket states München HB - Nuremberg or München Flughafen - Nuremberg? 

Is your ICE ticket a Sparpreis o supersparpreis (Saver/Supersaver I think in English)? 
Only if it is a Flexiticket the city transport (city ticket) is included, and it is valid in Nuremebrg and part of Munich. but not from/until the airport.

Comment: We had a bunch of questions on that, some rules changed recently and I seem to recall that it depends on the fare type. Is it a “Flexpreis” or “Sparpreis” ticket? Does it say “+City”? I believe [the airport is definitely out](https://www.mvv-muenchen.de/ticketshop-preise/tickets-tageskarten/city-ticket/index.html) but with this additional info, someone should be able to provide a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @EarlGrey city tickets are in some sparpreis tickets I think.

Comment: @ave yes, DB started to offer it as a paid option on Sparpreis and SuperSparpreis

Comment: @ave there is the option to buy it with the sparpreis, the option is there since decades, but from the tone of the question I assume it has not been bought.

Answer (score 14):

If you had bought a ticket from Munich Airport to Nuremberg, it is possible to buy a through ticket, you could have used it on the S-Bahn from the airport to Hauptbahnhof. If you only bought a ticket from Munich Hbf to Nuremberg, you can not use it on the S-Bahn from the airport into the city.

You can use your ticket for a single trip on the Nuremberg underground within the city limits if you bought it with the city option. In that case, the destination will be printed as Nürnberg+City. If you don't have the city option, the destination will be Nürnberg Hbf and you can not use it on the underground. Note that a section of the U1 line (Stadtgrenze-Hardhöhe) is outsite the city borders, where the ticket is not valid even if you had the city option.

Comment: you should add a sentence or two on the city ticket in munich. When you have +city at the arrival, you also have it at departure, but in munich the airport is too far out to be reachable with the city ticket

Comment: @FlyingTeller I didn't, because it is of no relevance. As you say yourself, having the city option in Munich would not cover the local train from the airport to the city centre.